# UiButton an "Interface Builder only" solution to resize font of title label in a responsive way

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to create a full responsive view in interface builder. I have alredy managed all the views width with a percentage value, i have set all my uilabel to shrink correctly the text based on variable width. The only thing i can't manage is the uibuttons... 
I can't find a way to shrink the title of my button.

- I create a button that occupay the 40% of the view width
- I open the Larger ipad preview in xcode (in MainStoryboard). Here the right proportion of the title is a 45 font size
- I open the iphone5 xcode preview (in MainStoryboard). Here the text is cutted and the font is always a 45

I wanna have the same proportion beetween title and button-frame, it can be achived down-scaling the font size. There is a way to achive this result with Interface Builder only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use size classes to assign a different font, but that might not give you the granularity you need (you could have a different font for iPad than iPhone, but not easily between iPhone SE and iPhone 7 Plus). You'd need some code to get more involved than that.  For example, `UIButton` has a `titleLabel` property that you could write code to automatically shrink the font, I think, but not in interface builder.